# Getting an img and adding html around it

Tags: jquery

I get my image via:

```
var img = $('#test-img');
```

I then wish to add additional html to this img:

```
var template = '<div class="crop">
        '+img+'
                <div class="crop-fade"></div>
                <div class="crop-box">
                    <span class="crop-img">
                        '+img+'
                    </span>

                </div>
            </div>';
```

So I do:

```
img.replaceWith(template);
```

But the image is not showing up - why?

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is all wrapped up so it only executes once everything is loaded.

Comment: Because you are trying to convert a jQuery object into text, which does not make sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`img` is a jQuery object and your template is HTML - get the `outerHTML` of the image, then use that to create your template:

```
var img = $('#test-img')[0].outerHTML;
var template = '<div class="crop">
    '+img+'
            <div class="crop-fade"></div>
            <div class="crop-box">
                <span class="crop-img">
                    '+img+'
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>';
```

Now append your `template` to a container

Comment: How will this get the img from the page?

Comment: You'll then lose any `src`, `class`, etc. that might have been part of the original image.

Comment: Alright, made the edit - use `outerHTML` to get the `img` html and you can use that in your template.